# Resistor on transimpedance amplifier input?

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode

I am currently examining an expired patent file of a photoelectric sensor. The file includes the circuit, I am trying to understand it with my limited analog electronics knowledge:

[Patent no: US6455839B1](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/f4/e6/09/624b103676eeb0/US6455839.pdf)

[image: Circuit diagram]

The circuit is on Page 3 - Fig 2. I am stuck at the first part of the circuit (the photodiode amplifier). From other photodiode amplifier circuits I have researched, none of them had the resistor in the inverting input. It's not mentioned in the PDF (not even numbered). Only thing I could think that it may be forming a series RC circuit with the parasitic capacitance of the photodiode, so it may be dampening high frequency noise by increasing time constant. Or am I thinking too deep?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, it is not needed, yet more parts are needed for Vref above CM minimum and Cf for matched **RfCf = RshCpd** = diode values at desired optical current levels for best step response.

Then gain ratio may be selected to trade-off with rise time and sensitivity.

https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2017/jul/design-transimpedance-amplifiers-for-precision-opto-sensing
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the source. I will be designing a photoelectric object sensor though, I think I won't be needing this much of complex calculations. Still, I would appreciate book/article recommendations on the topic.

Comment: Under rare conditions of high impedance Rf.>Rsh    adding Ri input may reduce overshoot.